# Resource Manager dies immediately and does not run

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, resourcemanager

I am trying to setup **hadoop 2.7.3** single node cluster on my machine. At one time, I successfully ran all the services and ran my custom jar file which worked fine.
After stopping and starting the services again later, I found out that Resource Manager is not running. I start the services using:

```
start-dfs.sh
start-yarn.sh
```

Doing `jps` gives:

```
14755 ResourceManager
13396 DataNode
14884 NodeManager
13606 SecondaryNameNode
15099 Jps
13262 NameNode
```

which is fine, but after sometime when I run my jar file,it stucks at this:

```
17/09/08 12:54:59 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:8032
17/09/08 12:55:01 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
17/09/08 12:55:02 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

By doing `jps` again shows Resource manager not running. I am very confused about this, tries lots of solution but not found a single solution.

Here is my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       salman-home
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
#::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
#fe00::0 ip6-localnet
#ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
#ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
#ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I have disables the firewall by `sudo ufw disable`

Here is my yarn-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>127.0.0.1:8032</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
<value>127.0.0.1:8030</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
<value>127.0.0.1:8031</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost/</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was bit silly of me. That port was be used by `InfluxDB`. Resource manager tried to acquire it but that tug of war always won by Influx. By stop Influxdb service, I solved this problem.